# Waiting for specific threads in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, events

I have 3 threads : A, B and C.

They are in *threads* list and are triggered at the same time with

```
A.start()
B.start()
C.start()
```

I do not know which thread will finish first.

I need to trigger action for each thread when it finishes, like that :

```
for t in threads:
    t.join()
    action()
```

**This code is not correct in this case** because : I have to wait for first A thread to finish before the B is checked, and wait for B to finis for C to be checked etc...

How to wait for each thread in an independent way, as if ".join()" was an event ?

Comment: How do you create the threads?

Comment: There is no need to `join`. Just check `is_alive` for each of them in a loop until one of them says it isn't.

Comment: thanks you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question leaves out many details, so I guessed and have come up with the following to demonstrate one approach:

```
from random import random
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

def callback(name):
    print('thread {} finished'.format(name))

A = Thread(target=lambda: sleep(random()))
B = Thread(target=lambda: sleep(random()))
C = Thread(target=lambda: sleep(random()))

A.start()
B.start()
C.start()

threads = {'A': A, 'B': B, 'C': C}
while threads:
    for name, thread in sorted(threads.items()):
        if not thread.is_alive():
            callback(name)
            threads.pop(name)
            break

print('done')
```

Typical output:

```
thread C finished
thread A finished
thread B finished
done
```

Comment: This is a bad idea. Your main thread is trying to use 100% CPU busy-polling the threads. If they don't do anything, this means you're at 100% CPU instead of 1%. If they _do_ need to do anything, this means you're stealing the GIL from them. (Even if they're mostly-I/O with a bit of CPU, having four threads fight over the GIL instead of three can make a significant difference.)

Comment: @abarnert: Normally I wouldn't code a busy-waiting loop like that for the reasons you mentioned. In this case I did however because without additional details I thought "why not?". If hammering the CPU is a problem, one could simply put a `time.sleep(.001)` statement in the inner or outer loop to briefly release it.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a way to wait on a thread group, and Python's API doesn't provide that. So, you have to simulate it.

---

The simplest, but least efficient, way is just to busy-poll the threads:

```
while threads:
    for thread in threads:
        thread.join(timeout=0.1)
        if not thread.is_alive():
            action(thread)
            threads.remove(thread)
            break
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

---

A better solution is to use a sync object that all of the threads can signal right before they exit. You can do this with a simple `Event`:

```
while threads:
    evt.wait()
    evt.clear()
    for thread in threads:
        if not thread.is_alive():
            thread.join()
            action(thread)
            threads.remove(thread)
            break
```

However, this has the same potential race condition as any self-resetting event: you can miss triggers. In some cases, you can work through all of the details and determine that the race can't cause any harm. If not, you have to use something slightly more complicated, like a `Condition`.

---

Or you could just jump to a higher level and use a `Queue` that threads can just `q.put(self)` before exiting. Then the main thread is easy to get right:

```
while threads:
    thread = q.get()
    thread.join()
    action(thread)
    threads.remove(thread)
```

---

But it's worth considering whether you actually need 3 thread functions here, or 3 task functions that you can run on a pool or executor, or maybe even 1 task function with 3 different args.

For example, it's hard to get simpler than this for a single function with 3 sets of args:

```
with multiprocessing.dummy.Pool(3) as pool:
    for result in pool.imap_unordered(func, [arg1, arg2, arg3]):
        action(result)
```

Or, for 3 functions:

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as ex:
    fs = [ex.submit(func) for func in funcs]
    for f in concurrent.futures.as_completed(fs):
        action(f.result())
```

Or you can even just tack the `action` onto the futures:

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as ex:
    for func in funcs:
        ex.submit(func).add_done_callback(action)
```

Comment: Looks to me like many of your suggested code loops mutate the object being iterated, which can cause problems as I'm sure you're aware.

Comment: @martineau I was missing a `break` in one of them; fixed it, (Although it might be clearer to iterate a copy instead of `break`ing?) Thanks. The others, I'm not mutating the object being iterated; I'm only mutating an object being used in a `while obj:` loop, which is fine.